# dynamic_cast in assert Causing Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, assert, dynamic-cast

<strike>I'm using the antiquated Visual Studio 2008 (let me save you the trouble "there's your problem".) This seems to be a problem with Visual Studio: http://rextester.com/XKFR77690</strike> This seems to be a problem with the `assert` macro: http://ideone.com/bhxMi0

Given these structs:

```
struct base { virtual ~base() {} };

template <typename T>
struct Foo : base { T foo; };
```

I can do this:

```
base* test = new Foo<pair<int, int>>;

if(dynamic_cast<Foo<pair<int, int>>*>(test) != NULL) cout << "hello world\n";
```

But when I use the exact same code as is in the `if`-statement in an `assert`: `assert(dynamic_cast<Foo<pair<int, int>>*>(test) != NULL)` I get an error:

> warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro `assert`
>   error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'

Incidentally I can fix this by using a C-style cast: `assert((Foo<pair<int, int>>*)(test) != NULL)` But I think that the C-Style cast will do a `static_cast` not a `dynamic_cast` which I don't want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`assert` is a macro. It's handled by the preprocessor which knows nothing about C++ constructs. So the following:

```
assert(dynamic_cast<Foo<pair<int, int>>*>(test) != NULL)
```

expands to a function-like macro taking two arguments, which in this case are:

```
dynamic_cast<Foo<pair<int
```

and

```
int>>*>(test) != NULL
```

Remember that function-like macro arguments are separated by commas. That is all the preprocessor sees. So in this case it sees 2 arguments instead of the 1 argument required by `assert`.

Your C-style cast version works incidentally because of the parentheses, which have higher precedence than the comma. Putting them around the `dynamic_cast` does the job as well.

Comment: Re: "answer below me" -- SO rearranges answers depending on various factors, so "below" and "above" can change. Right now, for instance, I don't see any answer below yours, but I do see one above it.

Comment: @PeteBecker I spent 20 seconds searching for the right word and *below* was my last resort...

Comment: @DeiDei Just link the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Yup: macros treat top-level commas as argument separators. The simplest fix is to put parentheses around the offending code:

```
assert((dynamic_cast<Foo<pair<int, int>>*>(test)) != NULL)
```

or, if you prefer, parentheses around the entire content:

```
assert((dynamic_cast<Foo<pair<int, int>>*>(test) != NULL))
```

The reason the C-style cast in the question compiles is not that it's a C-style cast, but that it puts the template code in parentheses, so the comma is no longer at the outermost level.